# cellForRowAtIndexPath called before viewWillAppear iPhone SDK 3.2 plus

Tags: iphone, sdk, viewdidload

After upgrading my SDK version I noticed that cellForRowAtIndexPath is always called prior to viewWillAppear. Previously the order of execution was opposite: viewWillAppear would always be called prior to cellForRowAtIndexPath. Because my application logic often used viewWillAppear to initialize objects that are subsequently used in cellForRowAtIndexPath, the application is often crashing.

I tried searching for an official expiation regarding this change with no success. I can likely move my initialization code to viewDidLoad, but wanted to see if there are better solutions or more information about this change in behavior.

Comment: Sounds like you already answered your own question.  You may still have to use `viewWillAppear` for resetting some items on the table (i.e. button states, labels, etc.) since `viewDidLoad` doesn't get called every time

Comment: Absolutely. What I did not make very clear above is that prior versions of SDK always called viewWillAppear prior to cellForRowAtIndexPath hence there's apperent change in behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the line

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

at the end of viewWillAppear and your problem will be fix

Answer (score 1):

It is not "`cellForRowAtIndexPath` called before `viewWillAppear`", it is `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` will call UITableView's delegate.

I made the same mistake and it took me a lot of time to find it.